# pip install import-java, PermissionError Windows 10

Tags: java, python, pip

I tried to install the package "import-java" for python, first there was an error because of the missing path for JAVA-HOME, but now i added this path and i have another error, a permission error and don't know how to fix this.

That is the Command Output:

```
Collecting import-java
  Using cached import-java-0.6.tar.gz (4.3 kB)
Collecting pyjnius
  Using cached pyjnius-1.2.1.tar.gz (40 kB)

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\JOSHUA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pyjnius\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\JOSHUA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pyjnius\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\JOSHUA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pyjnius\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\JOSHUA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pyjnius\
    Complete output (16 lines):
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\JOSHUA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pyjnius\setup.py", line 92, in <module>
        compile_native_invocation_handler(*get_possible_homes(PLATFORM))
      File "C:\Users\JOSHUA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pyjnius\setup.py", line 82, in compile_native_invocation_handler
        subprocess.check_call([
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 359, in check_call
        retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 340, in call
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I hope someone knows how to fix this, thanks.

Comment: run it as administrator, in linux just use Sudo

Comment: i have already tried to run the cmd as administrator, it doesn't work.

Comment: sorry then, don't know too much about windows

Comment: Is [`javac`](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/blob/307659b13c1e5583fcb25603b7d3732265ffd4a0/setup.py#L82) in the `%PATH%`?

Comment: Are you using 32 bit python on purpose? If not, uninstall and use 64 bit python